# What are applications of tree search algorithms?

Tags: algorithm, search, tree, graph-algorithm

I am looking for examples of practical **applications of tree search algorithms**, alpha-beta pruning in particular. The most commonly given examples in literature is game solving in checkers or chess, but I am interested in other possible applications. To narrow down my search, let's focus life sciences.

Comment: Write a sudoku solver and you will see. ;)

Comment: Every problem in NP *can* be framed as a search problem on a (possibly implicit) tree, though there are often faster ways.